# Fuzhen -Zhang linear algebra Problem Page No.112

Tags: inner-products

For $M_n (\mathbb{C})$, the vector space of all $n \times n $ complex matrices,

if $\langle A, X \rangle \ge 0$ for all $X \ge 0$   in $M_n{\mathbb{C}}$,then $A \ge  0$

which  of the  following define an inner product on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

$1)$$ \langle A, B\rangle = tr(A^*B)$

$2)$$ \langle A, B\rangle = tr(AB^*)$

$3)$$\langle A, B\rangle = tr(BA)$

Taken from Zhang linear algebra books page no .112.

[image]

**My attempts:**
I read this Wikipedia article, but could not get any idea on how to clarify  these options:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Any hints/solutions will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You've already asked that question like an hour ago. Why do you ask it again?

Comment: @amsmath..there was no response  so  i have uploaded

Comment: That's a lie. There was a lot of response in the comments. Actually, there was no response from you!

Comment: @stupid It is good that you posted a new question where you added some of the context requested in the other post.  However, it would have been better if you had edited your original question to include this information.

Comment: soory  sir  @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For an inner product, the following statements need to be true:

- $\langle p A, qB \rangle = p \overline{q} \langle A,B \rangle $ for $p,q \in \Bbb C$ *($\bar q$ here denotes the conjugate of $q$)*
- $A \neq 0$ implies that $\langle A, A \rangle \neq 0$

These two properties will allow to eliminate the two options that fail to be inner products (in the sense defined by Zhang). The remaining definition indeed yields a valid inner product.

Answer (score 1):

From $(b)$ we can see the positive-definiteness of 1) and 2)
3) isn't positive-definite.
Linearity comes from the linearity of trace operator for 1) and 2)
Conjugate symmetry:
For 1),
$N_1(B,A) =  tr(B*A) $ but by $5.21$ being a inner-product, $ N_1(B,A) = N_0(A,B) = \overline{N_0(B,A)} = \overline{N_1(A,B)}$
For 2),
$Tr(AB) = Tr(BA)$. And 1) is an inner-product. So 2) is an inner-product.